# Why does "pre-allocating..." still happen during -reindex?

Tags: reindex

I thought `-reindex` read blocks from disk to rebuild the index, without downloading the chain from the network. If that's so, why is bitcoind allocating memory in the files on disk? Like this:

`Pre-allocating up to position 0x3000000 in blk00205.dat`

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you provide some more of your debug.log?

Comment: Ok I must have done something else wrong. At the top of the log is the message `2017-04-22 18:37:28 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 209
` even though the directory `~/.bitcoin/blocks/` contains files up to `blk00834.dat`. The first `pre-allocating` message in the log continues from `blk00209.dat`

I started with `-reindex` earlier today, stopped and then restarted a few times...